# Rails 3.2.8 + RestKit - Mapping without KVC

Tags: ios, restkit, xcode4.5

So I am trying to grab information in JSON from my rails app with RestKit

My code to do so is like so:

**App Delegate**

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    //Initialise RestKit
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myapp.dev"];
    AFHTTPClient* client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:URL];

    //Enable Activity Indicator Spinner
    [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;


    [client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];


    RKObjectMapping *eventMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Info class]];

    [infoMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"sample":@"sample",
     @"sample_1":@"sample_1"
     }];

    RKResponseDescriptor *infoDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:infoMapping
                                                                                        pathPattern:@"/info"
                                                                                        keyPath:nil
                                                                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:infoDescriptor];
}
```

**View File**

```
- (void)loadInfo
{

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

    [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"/info"
                         parameters:nil
                            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

                                NSArray *info = [mappingResult array];

                                NSLog(@"Loaded info: %@", info);


                                _info = info;


                            } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error getting into"
                                                                                message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                                delegate:nil
                                                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                [alert show];
                                NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);

                            }];
}
```

The problem is. On the log output, RestKit tells me it maps everything successfully. But then when I attempt to view the object with both the method to log in the view file and with the debugger using `po` I get the following

```
374 Finished performing object mapping. Results: {
    "<null>" = "<Info: 0xa291b30>";
}
```

I can't view the object and with breakpoints it shows up as:

[image: Object exists but cannot view it]

I've been struggling with this for a few days and I'm not sure what else to try. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem. I'm not too sure why, but when I did the following it fixed it.

```
- (void)loadInfo
{

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

    [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"/info"
                         parameters:nil
                            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

                                NSArray *info = [mappingResult array]; 
                                NSLog(@"Loaded info: %@", info);                                  
                                _info = info;


                            } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error getting into"
                                                                                message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                               delegate:nil
                                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                [alert show];
                                NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);

                            }];
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    //Initialise RestKit
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myapp.dev"];
    AFHTTPClient* client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:URL];

    //Enable Activity Indicator Spinner
    [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;


    [client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];


    RKObjectMapping *eventMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Info class]];

    [infoMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"sample":@"sample",
     @"sample_1":@"sample_1"
     }];

    RKResponseDescriptor *infoDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:infoMapping
                                                                                        pathPattern:@"/info/:id"
                                                                                        keyPath:nil
                                                                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:infoDescriptor];
}
```

Comment: This works for a single object. But say your rest api (from Rail in this case) returns multiple objects. How do you map them all in a single object?

Comment: Whats your response.body like?

Comment: It's (null) even though it has contents

Comment: Have you used http scoop or wireshark to sniff the response packet to see what the content looks like? Can you post the contents?

Comment: gist.github.com/4462594 

I removed some information due to sensitivity. But I am trying to map one object with each of those JSON entries as a part of it and organising them by their ID

Comment: I think your path pattern needs to be "/info/:id" rather than just "/info"

Comment: I also tried that. Seem to still have the same issue unfortunatly

Comment: Did you try that when setting the infoDescriptor or objectManager getObjectsAtPath: ?

Answer (score 1):

When you load an object representation that does not have a nesting keyPath, RestKit stores the mapped objects under the `[NSNull null]` key within the dictionary (since `nil` is not a valid dictionary key). You can retrieve the mapping results either by calling `firstObject`, `array`, or `dictionary` on the `RKMappingResult` object to access the mapped objects.

I see a follow-up question about mapping an array to a single object... what does your JSON look like and how are you trying to represent it?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4462594

I removed some information due to sensitivity. But I am trying to map one object with each of those JSON entries as a part of it and organising them by their ID

Answer (score -1):

```
 RKResponseDescriptor *infoDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:infoMapping
                                                                                    pathPattern:nil
                                                                                    keyPath:nil
                                                                                    statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Comment: You could explain your answers to help others also. Thanks.